# Eclipse: Is there a way to open all files modified?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I am using eclipse to wok on a mercurial repository.
How can I make eclipse open all of the files that include changes rather than opening them manually one by one?

It would also be nice if I could give eclipse a changeset id and it would open the files that have been added/modified in that changeset.